# Major or minor version bump for 0.x incompatible changes?

Tags: version, versioning

During major version zero (0.5.1) do incompatibile API changes cause a **major** or **minor** version bump?

[Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) 2.0.0 says to bump the:

> **major** version when you make incompatible API changes

But it also states:

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

Does major version zero imply that incompatibile changes may occur even with **minor** version bumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...The public API should not be considered stable"

Incompatible API changes during major version zero are completely fine, even expected. You should stay at 0.x.y until you have an API that is feasibly maintainable. Though you should strive for some sort of organization during the initial development phase, more or less anything goes.